# Auto-generate many alphanumeric strings in postgres and add them to JSONB as an array to insert

Tags: postgresql, generator, jsonb

I am trying to generate multiple alphanumeric strings in postgres, add them to an array within JSONB and then either return the new JSONB or begin inserting them into the database.

I have a basic setup and want to at least see what was created before I start the mass creation but the current error is `invalid input syntax for type json`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "StringGeneration" (
  "@length"              INTEGER
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(25) AS
$func$
DECLARE "i" INTERGER;
DECLARE "strings" VARCHAR(25);
BEGIN
    SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT chr((96 + round(random() * 25)) :: integer) 
    FROM generate_series(1,10)), '') INTO "strings";
    RETURN "strings";
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

If I can see what is created above, then I would want to wrap it in

```
DECLARE "i" INTERGER;
WHILE "i" < "@length" LOOP
    "i" = "i" + 1;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I did not structure the return values correctly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "PinGeneration" (
  "@length"              INTEGER
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(25) AS
$func$
DECLARE "pins" VARCHAR(25);
BEGIN
  SELECT array_to_string(
    ARRAY(
      SELECT CHR((96 + ROUND(RANDOM() * 25)):: INTEGER) 
      FROM generate_series(1, 10)
    ),
  '') INTO "pins";
    RETURN "pins";
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```